# How do I calculate mathematically the transform 3D I to be applied on my CSS?

Tags: html, css, 3d, css-transforms

I have simulated a 3D object using CSS: [a test](https://codepen.io/takenoteiamhere/pen/MLpJMm?editors=1100)

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

div#one,
div#two,
div#three {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}

div#one {
  transform: rotateX(70deg) rotateZ(45deg);
}

div#two {
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  top: 119px;
  left: -70px;
  transform: rotateX(20deg) rotateY(45deg);
}

div#three {
  top: 119px;
  left: 70px;
  transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(45deg);
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id = "one">
</div>

<div id = "two">
</div>

<div id = "three">
</div>
```

All those degrees from rotate and top or left are all gotten by trial and error. This method took me too much time to get it right and I don't think that this is the best solution to simulate 3D objects using CSS.

1. Is it possible to calculate mathematically so that I gain the exact numbers I need to use as the values in my transform?
2. If it is indeed possible, what mathematics basics do I need? Could you give me an example of the calculation of one of the values in the above example?
3. Is it good practice to use my method above to try and get a 3D object simulation? Should I use something else instead, for instance, gif?
   Can anyone suggest me in the right direction?
   Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you describe your wished transform? do you want your object to transform on 1, 2 or 3 axises ? You can probably use [rotate3d](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate3d)

Comment: here is another idea where I used less of transform and easier to adjust : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51578964/8620333

Comment: @JonasPraem I'm still practicing. Currently, I'm trying to make a cube out of rectangles (as can be seen) and try to simulate a cube rotating at one axis.

Comment: @TemaniAfif How did you get the `calc(50% * 1.14)` for the width of `square3` in the first solution?

Comment: It's almost equal to `1/cos(30deg)` where 30deg is the angle I have used for the skew

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see. So it's to adjust the length so that it becomes a rhombus from a parallelogram?

Comment: no it's to adjust the width to be the same as the other ... as you can see the ::before and ::after element have width:50% and they are skewed by 30deg .. the skew will make there width bigger and will be equal to 50% * (1/cos(30deg)) that's why I used that width.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't think the `skewY` makes the width bigger, only the height. How did you know that you needed to use `skewX` on `square3` to make it appear 3D and why `30deg` too?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer check this https://jsfiddle.net/0mvoeLax/ .. the green line is bigger than the black because of the skew .. I have applied skewY to my element making their visual width bigger that 50% (initially defined) and this width should match the width of the element where I didn't apply skewY (only skewX) that's why I need to multiply by 1.14 ... and I didn't know I need to use skewX, I decided to use skewX. It's one method among multiple ones. Check this :http://www.puzzles.com/puzzleplayground/CubeAngle/CubeAngleSol.htm to understand the 30deg which half the 60deg shown there

Comment: @TemaniAfif By width, do you mean the length of the green border-top? What led to the decision of using `skewX`? Sorry, I'm having trouble imagining the 3D shapes in my mind...

Comment: yes I mean the border-top that is also the width ... and I decided to use skew, because I found it to be the easiest solution to use (for me of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to calculate the exact numbers, although it is tedious.

To be able to do that you need to know at least Euclidian geometry in the space and in the plane and the rudiments of Linear Algebra like vector spaces and affine transformations.

To be honest the more math you know the better you do in computer graphics. So there is no limit in how much you should know, just try to learn as much math as possible from all the fields you find connected to the problems you are facing departing from the topics listed above.

About your particular method for doing 3d graphics using CSS I think it is not wrong, it is just hard to do it properly in that way and thus not very practical, at least not for a beginner in 3d graphics and animation. But still valuable for learning.

Comment: So is it better to calculate the numbers or is it better to achieve the effect I want using trial and error, if my math just average?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer From the point of view of software development it is better to calculate the numbers. So if you want to apply animations and see different perspectives of your objects then math is the only sane way to go.